# C system calls, delete the file

Tags: c, system

Right now, when I use write system call over and over again, it just appends to a file lets call file.txt if I were to call sys call write in C, on file.txt, it would just constantly. There is a circumstance where given that same file, I want to erase everything from it, and add just one line. How would I go by doing this? I don't want to create a new file, I want to working in that same file.

Thanks!

Comment: You should do basic research on the functions you are using before posting here. SO is not "I'm too lazy to read the man pages or even google the function name, help me out".com

Comment: This question needs code.

Comment: Read all [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) SO, to avoid having your questions down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `truncate` or `ftruncate` to cut the file to zero bytes. Then write the line you want. You don't need to close or re-open the file, you can use your existing handle.

Comment: Suppose the file is open, I would have to do the open command again with truncate passed to it?

Comment: No, just call `ftruncate`.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour depends on what mode the file was opened: sounds like you're currently open in `append` mode; you need to open as a regular write in order to get the behaviour you desire.

Comment: So having it in write will strictly overwrite its contents right?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `O_TRUNC` to `open()` or pass `"w"`, `"wb"`, `"w+"`, `"wb+"` or `"w+b"` to `fopen()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call fopen(), you need to pass it the appropriate mode: read, write, append, etc.  Here's a good review of [fopen()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).